# Сверстать стрелку из двух линий?

Tags: html, css

Как сверстать подобные стрелки? Похоже на линию dotted от border, но как её применить здесь - не знаю :( Или же только нарезать и вставлять png?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Да, верно, для блока используете свойство border, нужные стороны зануляете и свойством transform поворачиваете на нужный угол.

Приблизительно так:

```css
.arrow {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 50px;
  border: 5px dotted #b1d454;
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow"></div>
```

Только все же для большей кроссбраузерности (всякие IE8) лучше бы нарезать png я думаю.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь)